# Converting a Hangman guess to lowercase

Tags: javascript, beginner, hangman

I am very much a beginner (only if/else, for, while, slice etc) and I wrote Hangman game. I needed to put in there code saying "let’s transform the player's guess to lowercase one every time he inputs an uppercase letter". What do you think of my code?

```js
var words = ["fish", "monkey", "pioni", "agreable"];
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var answerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
}
var ramainingLetters = randomWord.length;

//Game circle
while (ramainingLetters > 0) {
    alert(answerArray.join(" "));
    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter or press cancel to exit game");
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Enter only one letter");
    } else if (guess == guess.toUpperCase()) { //MY CODE GUESSING
        guess = guess.toLowerCase();
    } else {    
        //renew game cycle
        for (var j = 0; j < randomWord.length; j++) {
            if (randomWord[j] === guess) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                ramainingLetters--;
            }
        }
    }

    // stop game 
}
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert(" Cool! this word was " + randomWord);
```

Comment: "Were my thoughts about appropriate code more or less right?" You should test your own code. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Sorry , i didnt know

Comment: What part of the code did you write yourself?

Answer (score 1):

1. The place is roughly correct, but you break the gameplay cycle: in case of upper case input, you correct it to be lower case, but you do not process it -- instead, you start over with "Guess a letter..." prompt.
2. More or less right, yes, just needs a small correction.
3. Your big `if` statement should look like this:

```javascript
if (guess === null) {
    break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Enter only one letter");
} else {
    if (guess == guess.toUpperCase()) { //MY CODE GUESSING
        guess = guess.toLowerCase();
    }     
    //renew game cycle
    for (var j = 0; j < randomWord.length; j++) {
        if (randomWord[j] === guess) {
            answerArray[j] = guess;
            ramainingLetters--;
        }
    }
}
```

So, the difference:

- when upper case input is encountered, your solution skips actual input processing ("renew game cycle" loop)
- new code does correct uppercase input, and then continues to the actual input processing